# FSEvents: kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot flag: not getting 'root rename' events

Tags: objective-c, fsevents

I'm creating FSEvents stream and passing the `kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot` flag. From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1455376-fseventstreamcreateflags/kfseventstreamcreateflagwatchroot?language=objc):

> **kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot** :
>   Request notifications of changes along the path to the path(s) you're watching. For example, with this flag, if you watch "/foo/bar" and it is renamed to "/foo/bar.old", you would receive a RootChanged event. The same is true if the directory "/foo" were renamed. The event you receive is a special event: the path for the event is the original path you specified, the flag kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged is set and event ID is zero.

So when "/foo/bar" renamed to "/foo/bar.old" I'm getting the event as expected. But when "/foo" directory is renamed, I'm not getting the event as I should've. What might be a possible reason?

Comment: Is `/foo` a mount point? That is, is it not technically within the device you're monitoring?

Comment: @KenThomases no. For example it is like "/Users/myUser/Downloads/foo/bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known "FSEvents" bug in OS X: http://www.openradar.me/8342264